# Angular 7: Unwanted spacing appears above keyboard for ios devices

Tags: html, ios, css, angular

I'm currently developing a chat platform with a textarea box in the footer. So far it looks fine, except when the user presses the send button the message, an extra white space appears above the keypad. This only happens on ios devices (the following was tested on an iphone 6s), android appears fine.

[image]

**chat.component.ts**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
     <div class="message">
   // contains chat code
</div>


<div class="footer" #footer>
  <!-- Chat box -->
  <textarea
    autosize
    #msgbox
    class="chatbox m-0"
    [minRows]="1"
    [maxRows]="10"
    [useImportant]="true"
    [(ngModel)]="messageToSend"
    (keydown.enter)="checkDeviceBefSend($event)"
    autofocus
    placeholder="Type a message"
  ></textarea>
```

**chat.component.scss**

```
$chatbox-initial-height: 42px;
$chatbox-padding: 24px;
$chatbox-send-btn-size: 32px;
$chatbox-camera-btn-size: 24px;
$chatbox-file-btn-size: 24px;

.page-wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100 - 243px);
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: $chatbox-initial-height !important;
  height: calc(var(--fh, 1vh));

  .chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: $chatbox-initial-height !important;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid $color-disabled;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 2 * #{$chatbox-padding} - 100px);
    max-width: calc(#{$max-width} - 2 * #{$chatbox-padding} - 100px);
  }

  .chatbox-camera-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .chatbox-file-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .chatbox-send-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: did you try setting `bottom:0px` for `.footer` ?

Comment: just added bottom:0px.. the spacing is still present